# How do i add -pkg:dotnet to a web.config in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xsp4

I have been given a web application written in C# which I would like to deploy on Mono if possible. 
In order to get the application to compile, I need to pass the -pkg:dotnet flag to the compiler.

dmcs -pkg:dotnet

I am currently using XSP4 for testing and when it compiles the application it generates compilter errors about missing assemblies. I was wondering what I need to add to web.config in order for it to pass the -pkg:dotnet to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You should install aditional package "libmono-cil-dev". This package required other packages as dependency. If You use GNU/Lunux Debian please use command as the user root:

```
apt-get install libmono-cil-dev
```